# Graph API - Get recent files from a particular site collection

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to fetch recent files from SharePoint Online using Microsoft Graph.

The API I'm using is :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent
```

But the results include files from all site collection. I need to restrict the results to only a single site collection.

After some research, I found that there is no direct API to restrict the site collection.

I also tried using adding filter like :

```
 $filter=sharepointIds/siteId eq 'site-id'
```

but it was also not working. It gave a `501 (Not implemented) error.

**Update:**

I found another API from Graph which is

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/insights/used
```

which is inside insights(beta) named "items viewed and modified by me"

But it again returns data across tenant and I need to restrict it to a single site collection. I guess filter conditions are not yet implemented for this API in Graph.

Is there any method to get recent files from a particular site collection? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One correction, `/me/drive/recent` isn't pulling from all site collections, it's pulling from the current user's OneDrive. This includes recent files held within their drive and any recent changes to files that have been shared with them.

As for finding Recent Files from a SharePoint Document Library, you need to make this request within the context of the `drive` you want to pull from. For example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives/{documentLibraryId}/recent
```

Comment: Is there a way to get recent files from all document libraries in a site collection?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I'd suggest grabbing the list of `Drive` IDs and then use JSON Batching to request the `/recent` for each of them.